# undefined reference to `curl_easy_init' on CLion/Mingw

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, clion, mingw-w64

I am trying to use curl inside c++ code. How should i do it properly ?

I have pasted libcurl.a & libcurl.dll.a in this directory:
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\lib

This is my CMakeLists.txt from CLion/Mingw

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3) 
project(tan)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -lcurl.dll")
add_executable(tan Tan/mail.cpp)
project(untitled6)
```

When I add "#define CURL_STATICLIB" i get these errors:

`````
reference to `curl_easy_init'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:84: undefined  
reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:86: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:91: undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:92: undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:93: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:98: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:99: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:100: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:103: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:107: undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:111: undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tam/mail.cpp:121: undefined reference to ````curl_easy_cleanup

Without "#define CURL_STATICLIB" i get these errors:

CMakeFiles\tan.dir/objects.a(mail.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:81: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:84: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:86: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:91: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:92: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:93: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:98: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:99: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:100: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:103: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:107: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_strerror'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:111: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_free_all'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/tan/Tan/mail.cpp:121: undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
`````

Comment: `-lcurl.dll` -- DLL's are not used in the build process -- they only come into play when your program is running.  So why in your command-line are you specifying a DLL?

Comment: The linker flag should just be `-lcurl` .

Comment: Even with `-lcurl` I an getting same errors. I saw it in other post on StackOverflow. Thats why I added it thinking that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody comes looking use this in `CMakeLists.txt`. The last line solved the issue.

Step1:
`Copy libcurl.dll.a in C:/curl.
No need to copy "libcurl.a" OR "libcurl.dll.a" at any other place. 
No need for #define CURL_STATICLIB in main.cpp file`

Step2: `Edit the CMakeLists.txt` as below.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)                                     
add_executable(tan Tan/mail.cpp)
project(untitled6)
target_link_libraries(tan "C:/curl/libcurl.dll.a")
```

Step3: If your program flashes quickly and closes. You might be missing some dll files. To check which ones you are missing , run the program (in my case tan.exe) with cmd. Take that dll from curl package (in my case curl-7.65.0-win64-mingw) and put it along side of your executable file. Make sure curl and your executable is compiled with same compiler. In my case it's Mingw.